# Query records based on selected date

Tags: asp.net, date, datetime, model-view-controller

How can I query records based on a selected date? I already know how to query based on roomId.

In BookingsController.cs:

```
var booking = _context.Bookings
                      .Where(b => b.RoomId == roomId)
                      .Include(b => b.TimeSlot)
                      .OrderBy(b => b.TimeSlotId)
                      .ToList();
```

In BookingModels.cs:

```
public int BookingId { get; set; }
public int RoomId { get; set; }
public DateTime BookDate { get; set; }
public byte TimeSlotId { get; set; }
.
.
```

Comment: You should check date in where condition with roomId..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query it by RoomID and a selected date you can go for something like this:

```
var booking = _context.Bookings
                      .Where(b => b.RoomId == roomId && b.BookDate == yourSelectedDate)
                      .Include(b => b.TimeSlot)
                      .OrderBy(b => b.TimeSlotId)
                      .ToList();
```

If the roomID is not needed in your case then something like this can help:

```
 var booking = _context.Bookings
                      .Where(b => b.BookDate == yourSelectedDate)
                      .Include(b => b.TimeSlot)
                      .OrderBy(b => b.TimeSlotId)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to write it like this

```
var booking = _context.Bookings
                      .Where(b => b.RoomId == roomId)
                      .Where(b => b.BookDate == bookDate)
                      .Include(b => b.TimeSlot)
                      .OrderBy(b => b.TimeSlotId)
                      .ToList();
```